# multiple foreign keys referencing single column in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it's possible to have 2 columns referencing a single column in a different table.

I have 2 tables `users` and `matches`

The `users` table contains all the user id's in the column `user_id` and the matches contains two columns `userA` and `userB`. Would it be wise, if possible at all, to reference both columns to the same column in the `users` table?

The reason why I want to use it, is because I've been told that it's best practice and that it allows the DBMS to optimize queries.

To explain a bit further, the matches table holds the id's of `userA` who has selected `userB`. If `userB` also selects `userA` then there is a match. Boils down to a dating app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it: userA from matches pointing to user_id from users, and also userB from matches pointing to user_id from users. This is valid.

Comment: there are no requirement that the two columns must be equal? if it is two different foreign keys the columns is only required to contain a reference to a value in the `users` table

Answer (score 0):

Logically `usera` and `userb` both are different entity. So, they shouldn't have same `userid`.

You can have something like

`users` table with `userid`

`matches` table

`usera` and `userb` column both referencing `userid` in `users` table

So the result would be

```
Users

userid 
1 
2 
3

Matches

usera userb
1     2
2     3
```

Comment: See aweis comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible.

Whether it's wise depends on the meanings of the columns. But it can make plenty of sense depending on what the matches table means. Other useful examples of that same pattern would be pairs of tables like "People" and "ParentOf"

```
People
------
Jane
Bob
Sally

ParentOf
--------
Jane, Bob
Bob, Sally
```