# two columns referencing a single column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

A similar question is asked here [multiple foreign keys referencing single column in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830116/multiple-foreign-keys-referencing-single-column-in-other-table/20830137#20830137) 
but the syntax is not shown in the answer. I would like to know how this can be accomplished in SQL server. The following syntax gives error

```
ALTER TABLE ItemIssue ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemIssue_Person 
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID, AdvisorID) REFERENCES Person (PersonID)
;
```

ERROR: Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns, table 'ItemIssue'.

```
--  Create Tables 
CREATE TABLE ItemIssue ( 
ItemIssueID int identity(1,1)  NOT NULL,
PersonID int,
AdvisorID int,
    )
;
CREATE TABLE Person ( 
PersonID int NOT NULL,
Name nvarchar(500),
)
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define two foreign keys, one for each column:

```
ALTER TABLE ItemIssue ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemIssue_Person 
   FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person (PersonID)
;

ALTER TABLE ItemIssue ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemAdvisor_Person 
   FOREIGN KEY (AdvisorID) REFERENCES Person (PersonID)
;
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. And I research this topic but I don't know why do two foreign key for one column of a another table? Do you explain this?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create one foreign key for two columns referencing one column. Create them seperate:

```
ALTER TABLE ItemIssue 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemIssue_Person_Person FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person (PersonID),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ItemIssue_Advisor_Person FOREIGN KEY (AdvisorID) REFERENCES Person (PersonID);
```

Answer (score 0):

To define two foreign keys, one for each column-

Table

Contract - HospidPharmacyId Column

Hospice-   HospiceID PK
Pharmacy   PharmacyId Pk

- Using Following Query we can apply 2 Foreign Key for 1 column.

Alter Table Contract
Add Constraint fk_pharmacyID Foreign Key ([HospIDPharmID]) references Pharmacy([PharmacyID])

Alter TAble contract 
Add Constraint Fk_hospId Foreign key ([HospIDPharmID]) references Hospice(HospiceID)

- In the Contract Table for column-HospidPharmacyId  we can insert common value in both the

tables. those which are present in hospice & not in Pharmacy then we cant insert that value in

contract table & vice versa.